# Java derby table multiple updates in java code with for loop only last update working

Tags: java, for-loop, jdbc, sql-update

I want to update more than one rows in derby db using for loop. But when I tried using the below code only the last specified item has updated.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        String c = "update myschema.tblsample SET date=?, particulars=?,amount=? where blndrcr =?and index =?";
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(c);
        for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
            st.setString(1, td.getText());
            st.setString(2, v1[j]);
            st.setInt(3, v2[j]);
            st.setBoolean(4, dr[i]);
            st.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(tnoe.getText()));

            int kk = st.executeUpdate();
            if (kk > 0) {
                System.out.println("Addedd successfully !");
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(sample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Any one please help me

Comment: Your WHERE clause depends on parameters 4 and 5, neither of which depend on `j`, so you just keep updating the same row for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked effectively.Hopes your assistance along as and when needed.